# hover state is quirky

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I have been working on a drop down menu, that has different colors for both parent and child, which change when in a hover state:

http://jsfiddle.net/cELJ6/1/

I have a small quirk with this though.

The `Home` link is fine as are the `Products` and `Section2` are fine when not hovered.

The problem is:

1) When I hover over `Product`, the color of the link needs to be white. (BG color is fine and working correctly)

2) When I hover over a child element, such as `Product1`, then `Products` link color needs to be white

Hovering between `Products` and `Section2` seems to be quite quirky. Sometimes the color is white, sometimes it is grey (#777)

Is there a way around this?

Thanks

Comment: why do you use javascript for that? there are simple css-only solutions possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's no quirk, that is how your code works.

The color-definitions in your javascript are applied as inline-style which is higher than then normal css-style. This applies the grey color and leads to the quirk. Why do you have javascript there anyways?

edit:
I edited your fiddle to how I suppose you want it to behave. I just moved the color-declaration from the `a` to the parent `li` while giving the `a` `color:inherit`.

http://jsfiddle.net/cELJ6/2/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('ul > li.leaf').each(function(){
    $(this).mouseenter(function(e){
        $(this).find('a').css('color','white');
    });
    $(this).mouseleave(function(e){
        $(this).find('a').css('color','#777777');
    });

   });

 $('.expanded > ul.leaf').each(function(){
    $(this).mouseenter(function(e){
        $(this).find('a').css('color','white');
    });
    $(this).mouseleave(function(e){
        $(this).find('a').css('color','#777777');
    });

   });
```